# Stable Node JS AMQP 1.0 Client (Event Hub)

Tags: node.js, azure, amqp, azure-eventhub

I'm looking for a stable AMQP 1.0 client for NodeJS so that I can consume events from Azure Event Hubs.

I have tried using https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10, but it chokes sporadically on certain payloads with messages like `malformed payload: Unknown code prefix: 0x30` and `malformed payload: Unable to decode bytes from message body: 005375b00002810c5b7b226576656e7474797065223` (...).

I would appreciate any direction people can offer for a stable AMQP 1.0 client in NodeJS. I am surprised that I have not been able to find one so far, since otherwise it seems Azure is failing to support an entire developer base.

Comment: Could you paste same code to help resolving the issue? I reviewed the node package. And I think it's unstable and in the development stage by now. So I suggest to use EventProcessorHost(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/#receive-messages-with-eventprocessorhost) for C#/.Net to implement consuming events function.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the (co-)author of https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10. The error you were seeing was due to large messages being split across multiple transfer frames - something we hadn't encountered before, so hadn't implemented. We just added support for this in v2.1.0, so please check out our library again.

My co-author uses this in production against QPID and has been for months, and we both actively support it as we have time, so if there are any instabilities or missing features, we will try our best to address them. Often they are just issues where we haven't needed a feature of the (incredibly large) spec or have misinterpreted the (incredibly scattered) spec details.

Comment: Hi, is https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10 still an actively maintained package? I would like to use this but if its not being actively maintained then not sure its worth it.

Comment: Hi @sij_a - I'm no longer actively maintaining the project. My co-author is maintaining it on a semi-regular basis, and I've been seeking help internally at Microsoft to try and take over maintenance duties.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the official JavaScript SDK for Azure Event Hubs, [@azure/event-hubs](http://npmjs.com/package/@azure/event-hubs) which internally uses [rhea](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rhea)